X-ray absorption edge, accurate theoretical predition possible?
It is well known that in X-ray absorption spectroscopy, the absorption spectrum shows discontinuities at some critical frequencies.
Is it possible to predict locations of these jumps theoretically? I guess it is not an easy problem as it is not just a single-particle problem. It is a many-body problem.

There is technically no condensed matter problem that is fundamentally out of reach of computer simulation, except that it would use too much computer time and memory. I mean, if the cheapest approximations get it wrong, you can keep improving them until you get to coupled cluster configuration interaction, which is so computationally expensive that we can practically only do up to about 12 electrons in the system. That is not even taking into account that actual real-world systems are not perfectly periodic. How precisely correct do you want the answer?

@naturallyInconsistent   The K-edge is generally on the order of 1000 eV.  I want a precison of 1 eV.

Then you are immediately in trouble. From doing many many experiments, it is found that the molecular environment in which these atoms are, easily get shifted by more than 100eV; this is why tables of such X ray spectrometry data list a lot of ranges, nothing as precise as down to 1eV. This means that you have to approximate the orbital interactions near valence and conduction bands to extremely high precision to predict this. Might be doable at that resolution, though.

X-ray absorption fine structure (XAFS) and its variants are commonly used to discern small energy shifts from the local environment. A good tutorial is at https://www.lehigh.edu/IMI/teched/GlassCSC/SuppReading/Tutorials.pdf
